Getting Invalid Identifier error of ORA - 00904 even when column name is same
I have used with statement to bring and fetch data in a procedure but while executing it I am getting error as

Error(550,37): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "Q2_DATA"."AR_LENGTH": invalid identifier

Here is my query


WITH    
    q1_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( SELECT   rj_span_id AS SPAN_ID,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code AS maint_zone_code,
                  Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS NE_LENGTH,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           AND      rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology IS NULL THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS UG_LENGTH,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS AR_LENGTH
         FROM     ne.mv_span@ne
         WHERE    Trim(rj_span_id) = PSPAN_ID
         AND      inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
         AND      NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9', 'i')
         AND      rj_maintenance_zone_code = PMAINTZONECODE
         GROUP BY rj_span_id,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code
        ), 
    q2_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( 
        SELECT span_id as SPAN_ID,
              maintenancezonecode       AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS NE_LENGTH,
              fsa_ug                    AS UG_LENGTH,
              fsa_aerial                AS AR_LENGTH
       FROM   tbl_fiber_inv_jobs
       WHERE  span_id = PSPAN_ID
        )
SELECT     
            q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE, 
            q1_data.NE_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.NE_LENGTH, 0) as NE_LENGTH, 
            q1_data.UG_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.UG_LENGTH, 0) as UG_LENGTH,
            q1_data.AR_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.AR_LENGTH, 0) as AR_LENGTH
            
FROM        q1_data q1
LEFT JOIN   q2_data q2  ON(q2.SPAN_ID = q1.SPAN_ID)
ORDER BY    q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE;



update
Here is the whole stored procedure


PROCEDURE Get_spaninfo_by_span_mz_new (pspan_id       IN NVARCHAR2,
                                         pmaintzonecode IN VARCHAR2,
                                         pspantype      IN NVARCHAR2,
                                         pspaninfodata  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  AS
  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY NUMBER;
  
  
  BEGIN
  
  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY :=0;
  
  SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY from tbl_fiber_inv_jobs 
        where span_id = PSPAN_ID
AND JOB_FLAG = 1;
  
      IF pspantype = 'INTERCITY' AND  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY = 0 
         AND Length(pspan_id) = 21 THEN
        BEGIN
            OPEN pspaninfodata FOR
              SELECT rj_span_id AS span_id,
                     rj_maintenance_zone_code                        AS
                     maint_zone_code,
                     Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS
                     ne_length,
                     Round(SUM(CASE
                                 WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE
                                      '%AERIAL%'
                                      AND rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE
                                          '%CLAMP%'
                                       OR rj_construction_methodology IS NULL
                               THEN
                                 Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                                 ELSE 0
                               END) / 1000, 4)                       AS
                     ug_length,
                     Round(SUM(CASE
                                 WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE
                                      '%AERIAL%'
                                       OR rj_construction_methodology LIKE
                                          '%CLAMP%'
                               THEN
                                 Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                                 ELSE 0
                               END) / 1000, 4)                       AS
                     ar_length
              FROM   ne.mv_span@ne
              --  FROM APP_FTTX.span@sat
              WHERE  Trim(rj_span_id) = pspan_id
                     AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
                     AND NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9',
                             'i')
                     AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = pmaintzonecode
              GROUP  BY rj_span_id,
                        rj_maintenance_zone_code; 
                        
END;                        
ELSE

    
WITH    
    q1_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( SELECT   rj_span_id AS SPAN_ID,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code AS maint_zone_code,
                  Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS NE_LENGTH,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           AND      rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology IS NULL THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS UG_LENGTH,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS AR_LENGTH
         FROM     ne.mv_span@ne
         WHERE    Trim(rj_span_id) = PSPAN_ID
         AND      inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
         AND      NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9', 'i')
         AND      rj_maintenance_zone_code = PMAINTZONECODE
         GROUP BY rj_span_id,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code
        ), 
    q2_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( 
        SELECT span_id as SPAN_ID,
              maintenancezonecode       AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS NE_LENGTH,
              fsa_ug                    AS UG_LENGTH,
              fsa_aerial                AS AR_LENGTH
       FROM   tbl_fiber_inv_jobs
       WHERE  span_id = PSPAN_ID
        )
SELECT     
            q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE, 
            q1.NE_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.NE_LENGTH, 0) as NE_LENGTH, 
            q1.UG_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.UG_LENGTH, 0) as UG_LENGTH,
            q1.AR_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.AR_LENGTH, 0) as AR_LENGTH
            
FROM        q1_data q1
LEFT JOIN   q2_data q2  ON(q2.SPAN_ID = q1.SPAN_ID)
ORDER BY    q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE;
                 
        
      END IF;
  END get_spaninfo_by_span_mz_new;



Update 2
Here is my updated version of procedure


PROCEDURE Get_spaninfo_by_span_mz_new 
(
    pspan_id       IN NVARCHAR2, 
    pmaintzonecode IN VARCHAR2, 
    pspantype      IN NVARCHAR2, 
    pspaninfodata  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
  AS
  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY NUMBER; 
  
 BEGIN  
  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY :=0;
  
  
SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO  VAR_PARTIAL_QTY from tbl_fiber_inv_jobs 
        where span_id = PSPAN_ID
AND JOB_FLAG = 1;

WITH    
    q1_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( SELECT   rj_span_id AS SPAN_ID,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code AS maint_zone_code,
                  Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS NE_LENGTH,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           AND      rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE '%CLAMP%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology IS NULL THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS UG_LENGTH,
                  Round(SUM(
                  CASE
                           WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                           OR       rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%CLAMP%' THEN Nvl(calculated_length, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                  END) / 1000, 4) AS AR_LENGTH
         FROM     ne.mv_span@ne
         WHERE    Trim(rj_span_id) = PSPAN_ID
         AND      inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
         AND      NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9', 'i')
         AND      rj_maintenance_zone_code = PMAINTZONECODE
         GROUP BY rj_span_id,
                  rj_maintenance_zone_code
        ), 
    q2_data (SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE, NE_LENGTH, UG_LENGTH, AR_LENGTH) AS
        ( 
        SELECT span_id as SPAN_ID,
              maintenancezonecode       AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE,
              maint_zone_ne_span_length AS NE_LENGTH,
              fsa_ug                    AS UG_LENGTH,
              fsa_aerial                AS AR_LENGTH
       FROM   tbl_fiber_inv_jobs
       WHERE  span_id = PSPAN_ID
        );
        


              IF pspantype = 'INTERCITY' AND Length(pspan_id) = 21 
                 AND VAR_PARTIAL_QTY = 0
              THEN
        
BEGIN
            OPEN pspaninfodata FOR

            SELECT rj_span_id AS span_id, rj_maintenance_zone_code AS maint_zone_code,
                     Round(SUM(Nvl(calculated_length, 0) / 1000), 4) AS ne_length,
                     Round(SUM(CASE
                                 WHEN rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE
                                      '%AERIAL%' AND rj_construction_methodology NOT LIKE
                                          '%CLAMP%' OR rj_construction_methodology IS NULL
                               THEN
                                 Nvl(calculated_length, 0) ELSE 0 END) / 1000, 4)  AS UG_LENGTH,
                     Round(SUM(CASE WHEN rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%AERIAL%'
                                       OR rj_construction_methodology LIKE '%CLAMP%'
                               THEN
                                 Nvl(calculated_length, 0) ELSE 0 END) / 1000, 4) AS AR_LENGTH
              FROM   ne.mv_span@ne
              WHERE  Trim(rj_span_id) = pspan_id
                     AND inventory_status_code = 'IPL'
                     AND NOT Regexp_like (Nvl(rj_intracity_link_id, '-'), '_9',
                             'i')
                     AND rj_maintenance_zone_code = pmaintzonecode
              GROUP  BY rj_span_id,
                        rj_maintenance_zone_code;
        END;    
        
ELSE        
     
     OPEN pspaninfodata FOR
     
     SELECT     
            q1_data.SPAN_ID, q1_data.MAINT_ZONE_CODE, 
            q1_data.NE_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.NE_LENGTH, 0) as NE_LENGTH, 
            q1_data.UG_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.UG_LENGTH, 0) as UG_LENGTH,
            q1_data.AR_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.AR_LENGTH, 0) as AR_LENGTH
            
FROM        q1_data q1
LEFT JOIN   q2_data q2  
ON(q2.SPAN_ID = q1.SPAN_ID)
ORDER BY    q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE;
     
END IF;            
 
END Get_spaninfo_by_span_mz_new;  




The problem is not with your WITH clauses, but your aliases at the bottom:
SELECT     
            q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE, 
            q1_data.NE_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.NE_LENGTH, 0) as NE_LENGTH, 
            q1_data.UG_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.UG_LENGTH, 0) as UG_LENGTH,
            q1_data.AR_LENGTH - Nvl(q2_data.AR_LENGTH, 0) as AR_LENGTH
            
FROM        q1_data q1
LEFT JOIN   q2_data q2 

You are aliasing q1_data as q1, and q2_data as q2. Once you put an alias on a row source (a table-like object in a from clause), any fully qualified references to columns in that table (as well as any table-referencing hints) must use the supplied alias, not the object name. So simply change it to:
SELECT     
            q1.SPAN_ID, q1.MAINT_ZONE_CODE, 
            q1.NE_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.NE_LENGTH, 0) as NE_LENGTH, 
            q1.UG_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.UG_LENGTH, 0) as UG_LENGTH,
            q1.AR_LENGTH - Nvl(q2.AR_LENGTH, 0) as AR_LENGTH
            
FROM        q1_data q1
LEFT JOIN   q2_data q2 


@hud, you didn't show that the SQL was embedded in PL/SQL at first. When you execute an implicit cursor in PL/SQL, you must fetch the results into local variables using the INTO clause. This will work only if the query returns exactly one row. If it returns multiple rows, you must either bulk collect it into a collection variable, or (more often) simply use a FOR [recordvar] IN ([query]) LOOP .... END LOOP; loop or an explicit cursor that loops through and explicitly FETCHes each result. See a basic PL/SQL introduction for examples. Your first question was about SQL; this is about PL/SQL

@hud, on closer look it appears that your proc is intended to return a ref cursor. If that's the case, then shouldn't you do the same OPEN pspaninfodata FOR for the second query that you're already doing for the first? That would work also, as it doesn't actually fetch any result at that point.

I tried by taking with condition in ELSE and it worked.. Thanks Paul
